# Android app launch performance

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask, android-activity

When I run my App on the android emulator log-cat tells me that it skipped 70 frames (when the app starts launching) and that it might be doing too much in on the main thread. How can I spread the load, or improve my app's performance. Do I need a load screen on start-up.

This is my launch activity,

```
package com.the.maze;

import android.app.ListActivity;  
import android.content.Intent;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;  
import android.widget.ListView;

    public class TheMazeActivity extends ListActivity{  
            String list[]={"New Game","Highscores","How to play","Settings","About"};
            Class classes[]={GameActivity.class,null,Instructions.class,null,null};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));

    }
        @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        try{
        Intent intent= new Intent(TheMazeActivity.this,classes[position]);
        startActivity(intent);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your machine specification? In general, emulator might lag a little bit, even if there's no high load in application's main thread.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't much improvements I can suggest you, and I don't see a heavy computation inside your code (if any!). Anyway these are my suggestions:

```
public class TheMazeActivity extends ListActivity{
    //make them static final  
    private static final String[] list={"New Game","Highscores","How to play","Settings","About"};
    private stativc final Class[] classes={GameActivity.class,null,Instructions.class,null,null};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        //no need for try catch, if you can perfectly find out, when to trigger!
        if [classes[position] != null){
            Intent intent= new Intent(TheMazeActivity.this,classes[position]);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
   }
}
```

But be aware that these changes are only what is called [micro-optimization](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html)

Comment: do you know if android loads all the application activities when it's launched or does it load them as they are started

Comment: of course, it loads all activitys only when theiy are launched. I think currently no phone is capable of running 100+ Apps simultaneosly